# CSOM: Intermittent Tenant Errors "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

We have been seeing intermittent "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." when querying the tenant this week.

This occurs when either creating a new site, or trying to obtain site properties via the tenant using CSOM connected to the admin site (https://mydomain-admin.sharepoint.com/)

The command works one minute, then stops working the next, and fluctuates between working and not working.

Has anyone else been experiencing these issues?

An example of one of the commands which intermittently fails:

```
SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter filter = new SPOSitePropertiesEnumerableFilter()
{
    IncludeDetail = true
};
var props = tenant.GetSitePropertiesFromSharePointByFilters(filter);
tenant.Context.Load(props, p => p.NextStartIndexFromSharePoint);
tenant.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft are aware of this issue and it is being discussed on GitHub here: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3765